# Immutable Borrow in None Option

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

##### Example Code:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<&i32, String> {
        match self.bar() {
            Some(d) => Ok(d),
            None => {
                if self.check() {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 1"))
                } else {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 2"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn bar(&mut self) -> Option<&i32> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn check(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Rust playground Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f955fe10c348560c7e028a9e2bfc126)

---

##### Problem

- In the `Foo::foo` function:

  - `self.bar()` requires mutable borrow.
  - `self.check()` requires immutable borrow.

The above code fails to compile. The lifetime checker complains about the two borrow (mutable and immutable).

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:8:20
  |
4 |     fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<&i32, String> {
  |            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
5 |         match self.bar() {
  |               ---------- mutable borrow occurs here
6 |             Some(d) => Ok(d),
  |                        ----- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'1`
7 |             None => {
8 |                 if self.check() {
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

---

#### Questions

##### Question 1

*Why the compiler prevent me to compile this code?*

Clearly I am missing something here, but...

The immutable borrow (i.e. `self.check()`) only happens in the `None` branch. The previous mutable borrow (i.e. `self.bar()`) should not bring any impact there, should it?

The same code might be written:

```
if let Some(d) = self.bar() {
   return Ok(d);
}

// What lifetime of `self.bar` is needed at this point?

if self.check() {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

##### Question 2

*How can I solve this problem?*

Please note:

- I do not want to move the check (i.e. `self.check()`) before the `match`. Merely because of performances: `self.check` might be expensive and in the "cold" path. If `self.bar()` returns `Some` I want to return as soon as possible from the function.
- I do not want to to introduce runtime overhead. (E.g., dynamic check for borrow -> `RefCell`).
- Of course, this is a dummy example. Just for the sake of demonstration. So be aware about it. For example:

  - `&'a i32` represent an example returned "data" that requires lifetime. In my real code you can imagine I have a complex object which holds some references (and thus require lifetime). E.g., `struct ComplexObject<'a>`.

Comment: question 1 cause borrow last for all the match question 2 change who call check https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59c028180a0132dc5cdd403acde23008 (thus the perfect answer require a concrete mcve)

Comment: The problem is that `fn bar(&mut self) -> Option<&i32>` implicitly implies `fn bar<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a i32>`, so the existence of `d` will extend the borrow of `self`. Is it possible to change it to `fn bar<'a>(&mut self) -> Option<&'a i32>`?

Comment: A way out is building with `RUSTFLAGS='-Zpolonius'`.

Comment: you could assign self.bar() to a temp variable `let b = self.bar();` and then `match b`

Comment: @PaoloFalabella that will not work, since the return value of `self.bar()`'s lifetime is bound to the lifetime of `&mut self` borrowed in `self.bar`, and the return value `Some(d)`, which contains a reference with the same lifetime as `&mut self` in `bar`, is used as the return value of the `foo` function. This causes `&mut self` borrowed in `self.bar` to be borrowed for the _entire lifetime_ of function `foo`, making any further borrows impossible. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 1

The problem is that in `Some(d) => Ok(d)` you're still holding a reference `&i32` with the same lifetime as `&mut self` of the `self.bar()` call. Lifetime elisions hide this, but the code would desugar into something like this:

```rust
fn bar<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a i32> {
    todo!()
}
```

The `self.bar()` result has lifetime `'a`, so does `d` in `Some(d)`. Since you're returning `d` from the function, `self.bar()` needs to stay mutably borrowed until the end of the function. This makes `self.check()` impossible to be borrowed.

To better visualize the issue:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Result<&'b i32, String> {
        match self.bar() {        // --+- "&'a mut self" borrowed
            Some(d) => Ok(d),     // --+- "'a" becomes "'b"
            None => {             //   |
                if self.check() { // --+- "&'c self" borrow failed attempt
                    Err(String::from("Error type 1"))
                } else {          //   |
                    Err(String::from("Error type 2"))
                }                 //   |
            }                     //   |
        }                         //   |
    }                             // --+- "&'a mut self" valid until here
    
    fn bar<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a i32> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn check<'c>(&'c self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

The return value of `self.foo` is `&'b i32`, which needs the same lifetime as the return value of `bar`, so `'a` needs to live *at least as long* as `'b`, thus `&'a mut self` borrowed in `self.bar` stays borrowed until the end of `self.foo`.

### Answer 2

There's three options I'd consider:

1. Change the return value of `bar` to be `Option<i32>` if moving is an option:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<i32, String> {
        match self.bar() {
            Some(d) => Ok(d),
            None => {
                if self.check() {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 1"))
                } else {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 2"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn bar(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn check(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

2. Split `self.bar()` into two separate functions, one that does the mutable operation and moves the ownership from the function to the callee, and one that returns `Option<&i32>` but borrows immutably:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<&i32, String> {
        let bar = self.bar_mut();
        match self.bar(bar) {
            Some(d) => Ok(d),
            None => {
                if self.check() {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 1"))
                } else {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 2"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn bar_mut(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn bar(&self, bar: Option<i32>) -> Option<&i32> {
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn check(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

3. Use `Rc` for multiple ownership if you cannot move the object at all:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Result<Rc<i32>, String> {
        match self.bar() {
            Some(d) => Ok(d),
            None => {
                if self.check() {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 1"))
                } else {
                    Err(String::from("Error type 2"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fn bar(&mut self) -> Option<Rc<i32>> {
        // Rc::clone the value here
        todo!()
    }
    
    fn check(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: The returned data (i.e. `&i32`) is only an dummy example. In my real scenario, I have a complex object `struct Object<'a>` which holds a lifetime internally

Comment: you can still consider moving the object in case you're generating it in `bar` and want to use it elsewhere. if that is not an option, I'd go with solution 2 then

Comment: added a 3rd answer that uses Rc